# What is this plant and the white stuffs?

Tags: identification, diseases, plant-care, bugs

This plant is in my front yard from previous owner and now I just pay attention.

It has white stuffs all over the places. What is it and is it normal?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The white stuff looks like [lichens](https://www.fs.fed.us/wildflowers/beauty/lichens/whatare.shtml), those are actually a good sign because it indicates clean air. Lichens are a symbiosis between fungi and algae.

Comment: Just to add @benn: they are not parasites, they just use branches and trunk to "nest".

Comment: Yes @GiacomoCatenazzi, thank you. I forgot to mention that they are usually not harmful for the plants/trees.

Comment: Try scraping off a cluster of a larger deposit to see if there's an insect under or in it please - what part of the world are you in, and is this plant an Azalea or something else? If you don't know what the plant is, have you ever seen it flower at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plant itself looks like an azalea.  I have one very similar but it does not have lichen.